# Col doesn't align side to side with Form

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have a react component and the columns aren't aligning side to side.
In my return statement I have:

```
    <Row>
      <Col md="6">
        <CarouselPhotos />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" />
        </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </Col>
    </Row>
```

In the example image.  The label email address appears correct next to the CarouselPhotos component but then the input field pushes all the way to the bottom.  It should be right below email address.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:
When no column widths are specified the Col component will render equal width columns.
This caused me to assume that Col didn't have to be set in the second Col since i thought it be rendered equally.  After adding Col width it now works.  It displays equally.

```
    <Row>
      <Col md="6">
        <CarouselPhotos />
      </Col>
      <Col md="6">
        <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGroupEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </Col>
    </Row>
```